Set Cursor Where Mouse Clicks On Emacs Terminal Through Configuration File
I am new to the emacs text editor. Whenever I use the text editor in terminal, I find that I need to use the arrow keys on my keyboard to navigate through the code. I find this to be cumbersome when navigating through long lines of code so I was looking for a way for the cursor to move wherever I click with my mouse.
I've added the following to my .emacs configuration file:
(mouse-set-point 'mouse-1)

from this website: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-Commands.html#:~:text=C%2DM%2Dmouse%2D1,window%20and%20setting%20the%20cursor.
(mouse-set-point 'mouse-1) doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Am I misunderstanding what the website is saying? If so, what is the correct one that should replace this?

Are you running emacs in the terminal? The manual section you've linked is talking about features in graphical displays specifically.  In a terminal, you could enable M-x xterm-mouse-mode

Yes I am running emacs in the terminal. I've added (xterm-mouse-mode 1) into my configuration file and it works now. Thanks
